# Is Google word2vec pertrained model CBOW or skipgram

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, word-embedding

Is Google's pretrained word2vec model CBO or skipgram.

We load pretrained model by:

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors as word2vec

model= word2vec.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz')
```

How can we specifically load pretrained CBOW or skipgram model ?

Answer (score 5):

The `GoogleNews` word-vectors were trained by Google, using a proprietary corpus, but they're never explicitly described all the training-parameters used. (It's not encoded in the file.)

It's been asked a number of times on the Google Group devoted to the `word2vec-toolkit` code, without a definitive answer. For example, there's a [response from word2vec author Mikolov that he doesn't remember the training parameters](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/word2vec-toolkit/qJ06CPKFzSM/IIqUEHqIFFgJ). Elsewhere, [another poster thinks one of the word2vec papers implies skip-gram was used](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/word2vec-toolkit/gHlyBfPSqd8/VvnDqnprAwAJ) – but as that passage doesn't precisely match other aspects (like vocabulary-size) of the released `GoogleNews` vectors, I wouldn't be completely confident of that.

As Google hasn't been clear, and in any case hasn't released alternate versions based on different training modes, if you want to run any tests or make any conclusions about the different modes, you'll have to use other vector-sets, or train your own vectors in varying ways.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but Mikolov describes the hyperparameters [here](https://groups.google.com/g/word2vec-toolkit/c/lxbl_MB29Ic/m/NDLGId3KPNEJ). The Google News pretrained vectors were trained using CBOW. I believe that's the only option for you to load; there is no pretrained skip-gram version available.